# count number of null and not null rows per attribute in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, count

Is there is a solution how to calculate the number of NULL and NOT NULL records per each attribute in the view?

For example there are 50 views and each one has 20 attributes and the result I'm expecting looks like (for example):

```
table_name -----Column_name---Nulls_count----Not_null_count------count(*)

T1 -----------------C1-------------------20---------------40-----------------------60          
T1------------------C2-------------------11--------------49---------------------60
T1------------------C3-------------------25--------------35---------------------60
T2------------------C1-------------------0--------------100---------------------100
T2------------------C2-------------------40--------------60---------------------100
```

all of views are stored in a sys.all_views and columns are in the sys.all_tab_columns and there is a link between them by table_name field. But there is a need to use a dynamic SQL or PL/SQL becouse there is a madness to  count(*) null rows for each attribute and then to count(*) not null rows for the same attributes in the views manually :)
Did anyone face with such task? I'll appreciate all your comments and help.

Comment: So are you looking for an Oracle specific way to count the nulls/nonnulls in a column without actually reading though the data?

Comment: Well, not exactly. I'm trying to avoid the manual listing the count(*) or count(attribute) function for all attributes. I just thought if it is possible to create, for i.e, a procedure with variables view_name and column_name and use the loops for counting all Nulls and not Nulls rows for each attributes in selected tables. And if it is possible can anyone  please share with examples. Thank you in advance..

Comment: I think you can get the information you want from USER_TAB_COLS.  Go thou and do good works.

Comment: Ok.   If you can select the desired columns out of the metadata views you described, then you should be able to write a dynamic query that gets what you need.  Davids answer is the correct way to do it.  doing your own loops will add overhead that you don't really need.   I am pretty sure you are stuck with a full table scan no matter what direction you take.

Answer (score 1):

Since the number of rows is count(*), you can get null and non-null rows per column with:

```
select
  count(*)               total_rows  ,
  count(col1)            col1_nonnull,
  count(*) - count(col1) col1_null   ,
  count(col2)            col2_nonnull,
  count(*) - count(col2) col2_null   ,
  ...
from
  my_view
```

Comment: Thanks, David. But I'm triyng to avoid in this case such approach. I mean, it would be greate if I had only one table, but in my case there are more then 60 views and each of them counts 20-30 attributes. And let's imagine, that I will need to support such script. So every time when new attributes will be added I had to create a 3 additional case for each of them.. Is there another way how to retrieve this information by using Dynamic SQL or PL/SQL?

Answer (score 0):

here is the correct select:

```
 select t.table_name, T.NUM_ROWS, c.column_name, c.num_nulls, T.NUM_ROWS -  c.num_nulls  num_not_nulls, c.data_type, c.last_analyzed
from all_tab_cols c
join sys.all_all_tables t on C.TABLE_NAME = t.table_name
 where c.table_name like 'MV_%' and c.nullable ='Y'
 group by t.table_name, T.NUM_ROWS, c.column_name, c.num_nulls, c.data_type, c.last_analyzed
  order by t.table_name, c.column_name;
```